# Display current column in status line

Tags: vim, statusline

How to display the current column in the status line?

Having read `:h statusline` I found `%c` which looks promising, but it counts
bytes and not characters. I'd like to have the column separated by characters,
not bytes. `%v` works if no tabs are being used. Here an example:

```
123 56789
“äå µåäö”
   ^ this is a tab
```

I'd like to display the number indicated in the first row. The following works
for the first to third column until the tab comes into play.

```
:set statusline=%v
```

The following works only for the first line, but not the second one.

```
:set statusline=%c
```

Given the abovementioned example vim displays `5` if the cursor is on the
digit *five* in the first row, which is what I want. If I move down one row so
the cursor is located on the `µ` I'd like to display `5` as well, `%c`
displays `9` and `%v` depends on the value of `tabstop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use an expression in the `'statusline'` option:  `%{<exp>}`.  So grab the line, trim it to the cursor column, replace all characters with a 1-byte character, and count the length of the string:

```
:let &stl = "%{strlen(substitute(strpart(getline('.'), 0, col('.')), '.', 'x', 'g'))}"
```